# Why my webpage styles look different when opened from my local drive than from rawgit.com?

Tags: html, css, git

I usually use `http://rawgit.com/<username>/<repo name>/master/<folder name>/index.html` to access my webpages from github. Sometimes the default stylings are not applied when I try to access my page from rawgit. But they appear when accessed from my local machine.

**Example:**

[this-link](https://rawgit.com/suryataparoy/OnCal/master/public/oncal.html)(where bootstrap button styles appear/look different when I open it from my local drive).

I am new to github. I have seen people using github.com to access links & not rawgit like mine. Is it what that is making my page look different ? I have also seen people using htmlpreview.github.com to access links.

I want to know what is the difference ? What is htmlpreview.github.com ?

How can i access my web pages using github and not rawgit ?

Comment: There could be differences between your local HTML files and the ones on GitHub.  This is the whole point of GitHub, to be able to change things locally while a master version exists on the repository.

Comment: You could try [github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/).

Comment: But I have the exact same file on GitHub as my local drive?They both should be same when rendered from the browser...